# Add constraints to programmatically generated elements

Tags: swift, xcode

I've seen a few examples of adding constraints programmatically by using anchors, but from my understanding that only works with reference to a `superview`.

My goal is to create `UILabels` on the fly and then position the next row of `UILabel`'s an even distance below the previous `UILabel`'s as I've illustrated in this [Visual Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czMxB.jpg).

Starting out, I have the `UIView` (green color) which is the `superview` I can reference to place the next row of `UILabels`(purple color), then I'll create the next row of `UILabel`'s (orange color) and will want to position them the same distance below the previous row of `UILabel`'s(purple color) and so on.

I was wondering if its possible to get the nearest neighbors or siblings if you will, bottom edge because I will be generating these on the fly and the `UILabel`'s are at the same order of hierarchy so to speak.

Comment: Look up UIStackView

Comment: Be careful with your idea. Adding stuff like UIView on the fly is rather heavy task. Assuming you're planning to have multiple UILables added on the fly that's pretty much a lot of work. I'd recommend going for UICollectionView in that case.

Comment: @inokey I'll look into UICollectionView. Is it possible to customize each CollectionViewCell's width and height or must they all be uniform?

Comment: @user8244799 in fact you can.

Comment: @user8244799 check this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: @inokey Wow this is exactly what I needed, thanks for your help!